# Show only content of the visitor

Tags: 2sxc

I have an app where I want visitors to be able to write down some text.
They are the only ones that are allowed to see their own entries.

In order to allow people to create an entry I have set the security of the content type: crud is permitted for those who have viewing rights.

In the query designer I have basically just the list of the content type. So, of course any visitor that can see the page, sees all entries.

How can I limit the results so the visitor only sees her/his own entries? If I add the ownerfilter in the query designer, the results come up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what you should do is give these permissions on the type:

1. Registered users (or those who may add) should have c permission (create). They must be logged in - so don't use "everybody" - otherwise you won't know who added it.
2. Owners (those who created the record) should have edit permission (I wouldn't give them delete)
3. In the visual query, you should then use the owner-permissions. As a host-user you can only test it, if you also made some records.

OK? otherwise just add more infos.

Answer (score 0):

Or just add a field that stores the username. When you show the entries, only show the ones where the current username matches the username field :)